# typescript doesn't recognize the result of function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have created a typescript util that return true if the parameter is a function and false if not, but when I use it to discriminate the way that I use a variable, typescript doesn't recognize the check.

util:

```
export function isFunction<T>(value: T | undefined): boolean {
return typeof value === 'function';
}
```

usage

```
isFunction(group) ? group(el) : group
```

Comment: By does not recognize you mean `isFunction` is not caught by compiler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite how user-defined type guards work:

```js
function isFunction(x: unknown): x is Function { // note the 'is'
  return typeof x === 'function';
}

const a = Math.round(Math.random()) ? () => 5 : null;
const b = isFunction(a) ? a() : null; // no error;
```

A rare actually valid use-case for the `Function` interface.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMXNeYAUAPALkXAGsw4B3MASiL2RUQ0lgUQG8BYAKEUQCcAplBD8kUAJ4AHQXGCJ6AXmWIA5KBbZVAbh4BfHjwgIUURAENEixAFlzUABYA6fnHAATHHccvzYd3AAtjjU1IgA-IghVgB8iACsiERgIAA2qbrcxmCmiABGVgzMWAg45mGR5tHJaRk8QA)

Comment: I tried `Function` but it felt too weird to use lol

Comment: @thurasw I hear you, think that's only the second time I've ever used it. First time was something like `interface SpecialFunction extends Function { (x: number) => string; [someSymbol]: "I am special"; }` because I needed the extra property typed.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is this [Type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). No need to use generics.

```
export function isFunction(value: unknown): value is ((...args: any[]) => any) {
    return typeof value === 'function';
}
```

[Working demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wZwDFUNsUAKANwEMAbJYALjlQGsUIB3FASmZvrA8%20OOXIA6SdSgBzfM2ooAngG0AujzgBeAHxxFSzQG8AUHHNwowGEii4YSsMAgI4Ahtq1a4AcmTosHB8AbhMAXxMTNBx8eH80bV9qfAATBB99ETYObkzRck1dNwhMFM0AHzhYqEwUGVDMV3ICYgCycnieYzMLAHpe4X1EEkDcAAtgKwBCHvN4gvCTYFp8IVMLOH7B6tqZOAnp2eH0cKA)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isFunction<T>(value: T | undefined): boolean {
    return typeof value === 'function';
}

let imFn = (val: string) => {
    console.log('i am a', val)
}

let imNotFn = 'not function';

function execute(anything: any){
    console.log(isFunction(anything))
    isFunction(anything) ? anything('function') : console.log(anything);
}

execute(imFn);
execute(imNotFn);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgMXNeYA8AVAPgAoA3AQwBsQBTALkT0QB9FwATa4GMatgSnoAjOHArUySAN4BYAFCIFiAE7UoIJUigBPAA7U4wROSrVEAXguIA5KEiwEVgNxyAvnLlioyALZokZxFJKehQoJW4Acz5zAkQZeUUIBBRRagA6CjgIoisYRDJvfKsAGiNKPld3WU8fADk4KD9zazAGxFssB2dZOQ77JGoAD2oIEChqIgktKAALSPopvnjFRCSwFLEMrKJUDDtsSbBpubAoioSFXcx%20w%20PI6IB%20fKPZyJy%207Cto%20jWN9MzslNXqc%20N03D1ZEMRmMJjBfGBQXIoaNxjtvPVGgjukA)